# How do I restore the old theme of FileZilla?

Tags: filezilla

I recently noticed that my upgraded FileZilla no longer has this theme:

[image: old FileZilla theme]

But rather this theme:

[image: new FileZilla theme]

I went through all of the themes in the settings:

[image: theme list]

And none of them match. Is it possible to create my own theme from the old images?

Comment: I guess this isn't a good enough question for this site since it has a -1, but I really want to know! I love the old theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I started downloading [FileZilla versions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla_Client/) going back to 3.14.0 and noticed that all of the themes were exactly the same as they are in the current version, so I downloaded the version that matched when I created this question, which was 3.23.0.2.

That version defaulted the theme to the new theme. I downloaded 3.22.2.2 and the theme defaulted to OpenCrystal. It turns out that they never created a new default theme, just changed the default! Sorry for the waste of a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can install old version of FileZilla and backup its icons:
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\FileZilla

Comment: I actually went to `C:\Program Files\FileZilla FTP Client\resources` and created a new folder `classical` to try figuring out which icons belonged to the old theme.Turns out I was completely off as I explain in my answer.